# "Throwing" in the type system and validating types

Tags: typescript

I sometimes create a type to do some sort of validation on input that I expect to be passed.

```
// Library code
type Validate<T> = T extends Something ? T : never

// User code
type MySpecificType = Validate<{/* ... */}> // never if the shape was wrong.

// later on...
const instance : MySpecificType
libraryApi(instance) // error, never. But should happen sooner.
```

This aids in type inference for larger, more complicated types. If someone has a mistake in their type shape then they'll end up with a never. The problem is that the type error while happen at some point down stream when they attempt to assign or use it in a function, rather than where they create the type.

Are there any other ways of short circuiting that process with just types? Sometimes I'm working with types primarily so there are no values to pass to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just constrain the `T` parameter to `extend` the desired type, this will give the error when you pass in the type to `Validate`

```
interface Something {
    x: string;
}
// Library code
type Validate<T extends Something> = T

// User code
type MySpecificType = Validate<{ x: string, y: number}>
type MySpecificTypeErr = Validate<{ x: number, y: number}> // err
```